# How to verify if the github syntax variables actually exist in github actions workflow yaml?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, yq

I have list of jenkins jobs which I'm converting to github actions using github actions importer.

Some conversions are adding syntax like `${{ env.some_variable }}`

But some of those converted workflow files doesn't have `some_variable` in the `env` block.

It's not being added in the next actions steps running as part of the jobs.

How do I verify if the `some_variable` exists in the `env` block if I encounter `${{ env.some_variable }}`

I tried some commands using `yq` parsing. But they're of no use.

Comment: You can lint your workflows with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/.

Comment: The issue here is that it checks for syntax. But I'm looking for whether the env actually contains the variable or not. It doesn't show any error if the var doesn't exist because the syntax is still valid.

Comment: Right. IIRC, it does check for output parameters. It may not detect env vars, secrets, or vars, as those may be configured at repo, org, or environment level.

Comment: @Underoos *Re: The issue here is that it checks for syntax. But I'm looking for whether the env actually contains the variable or not. It doesn't show any error if the var doesn't exist because the syntax is still valid.* -- Then your title is quite misleading as it literally asks how to check for correct syntax. Consider [updating](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76611427/edit) it.

Comment: @pmf edit suggestions please.

Comment: @Underoos You're not looking for syntax validation, so replace that with something that you actually are looking for. Maybe paraphrase the part following "I'm looking for" in your comment cited above, or the second-to-last paragraph from your question's body starting with "How do I verify". You know and can describe best what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple aspects to the question

> How to verify if the github syntax variables actually exist in github actions workflow yaml?

This is especially with `${{ env.some_variable }}`, as the parameter expressed here by the Github Actions Expression syntax is also an environment parameter that can be expressed in POSIX Shell Command Language syntax well at other places of the Microsoft Github Actions Workflow YAML, namely `run:`.

Which is an aspect you can easily make use of, as the Shell Command Language parameter substitution rules outline how to error – even with an optional message – when a parameter is unset or empty (null) or both.

Considering the string value of the property named "run" to be part of the workflow YAML (which it obviously is), it would already fall in this category. However, adding power to the shell does not yield this force:

```yaml
    run: echo "thou shall error on non-existence ${some_variable:?}!"
```

*(The default shell, not the *powershell*; just writing. [ref](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02))*

That is, the expression with the Github Actions Expressions syntax in question, `${{ env.some_variable }}`, it expresses what is the environment variable named "some_variable" within the string value of the run property given its syntax.

Now, such convenient substitution features you may only find in syntax of expressions of greater age and given that the Github Actions Expressions syntax has not yet aged, in comparison, you may find its properties limited, however there *is* an operator that at least can provide a default value.

Javascript-esque as it may be intended, the operators' syntax character sequence of two times the pipe symbol: `||`, also listening to the name "OR operator".

Now Github Actions Expressions do not have any concept of error handling apart from their syntax – there *are* syntax errors as you noticed – so they are by their definition error free otherwise. Therefore, this operator may only be used to provide a default value and not express an error condition per-se:

```
${{ env.some_variable || "if you can read me, some_variable does not exists" }}
```

*([ref](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators))*

So, while you can make the expression half-way self-asserting, you would then need to take care of the second half your own.

---

There is something dirty you could do to provoke a real error and that is to provide an object instead of a string/scalar ([literal](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals)), as IIRC this does not compute the expression at that level of the Github Actions YAML executor/runner and errors as the data type is incompatible.

It's a bit of living on the razors edge, so try before buy.

The [fromJSON()](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) function allows you to return an object and that data type should be *incompatible* within string context (inferred from *literal*), and perhaps already the function call errors with syntax-error-like, as *not* being JSON Text:

```
${{ env.some_variable || fromJSON('{"some_variable does not exists"}') }}
```

That is intentionally not JSON Text (wrong JSON) so hopefully it suffices to provoke an error with fromJSON(). If not (as this is intended, but also as written, you should try this first), the other approach would be to provide an object in the hope it errors in the string context:

```
${{ env.some_variable || fromJSON('{"error": "some_variable does not exists"}') }}
```

---

Contexts other than *env* are better validated, IIRC *input* for example. So you can make a composite action, define the inputs and if those are missing (while required, unset – not empty) there will be an error. You could then in the workflow map other contexts onto the `with:` properties resulting in better validation.